# How to add route to such url /index/viewmodel/id/{id}/ in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I have such code,but it is not worfing

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static ('viewmodel', array (
    'controller' => 'Index',
    'action' => 'viewmodel'
));
$router->addRoute('viewmodel', $route);
```

P.S: Working Code

```
$routerTwo = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':index/:viewmodel/:id', array (
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action' => 'viewmodel'
        ));
        $routerTwo->addRoute('viewmodel', $route);
```

Comment: hey! The default Zend Framework route should do the trick for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('index/viewmodel/id/:id', array (
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'viewmodel'
));
$router->addRoute('viewmodel', $route);
```

In the action you can access :id by `$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');`

Comment: It is not help. "Page not found"

Comment: Its worfing:                                                           $routerTwo = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
        $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':index/:viewmodel/:id', array (
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action' => 'viewmodel'
        ));
        $routerTwo->addRoute('viewmodel', $route);